# SSRS Report separate data into multiple sheets

Tags: sql-server, excel, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure that produces data for total sales for the month. I want to used the stored procedure to create a ssrs report, that separates each page by sales agents. The ssrs report will produce an excel workbook that with each tab in the book holding data for each rep for that month. How can I do this in SSRS?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a grouping on your tablix by sales agent.

Once you have the grouping follow these steps:

1. Right click on the grouping
2. Select Group Properties
3. Select Page Breaks
4. Check the "Between each instance of a group" option

This will split the workbook into tabs by sales agent. You can then name the tab after the sales agent as well by editing the Page Name in the Group properties pane. You will need to use a variable for this.