# How to get multiple pages in same report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I created one report, and created a parameter with dimension column, my requirement is when i enter one parameter report should filter with that value
when i enter two parameters report should have two pages based on the two parameter values.

any section related thing available in ssrs?

I referred here, something can be done through list, but list is allowing only test boxes, My report has too many tablixs to show

Thanks

Regards

Comment: I believe you could simply add a new tablix below your first one and use the `PageBreak` property to force the second page. Then you could define an expression that determines visibility of this second table based on the second parameter's value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a grouping in your tablix, this grouping should be based on the parameter dimension you mention in your question.

Once that is complete, set the tablix to page break for every different instance of the group. This will create a new page for each item in your parameter list.

In this question i gave a similar answer, with some detailed steps: [SSRS Report separate data into multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672462/ssrs-report-seperate-data-into-multiple-sheets/31673282#31673282)

This should be applicable to your question as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Kalim, 
but the problem is i am showing parameter value in header only, i have multiple tablixs in single report, even i tried grouping by Parameter value without showing them at tablix 
But when i select two values together it is showing same tablix1 for two parameter values then tablix2 but my need is it should show tablix1 and tablix 2 for first parameter value then Tablix1 and tablix two for second parameter value 
Please suggest

Comment: I think I understand what you trying to do now, however i dont have an exact solution. I suspect though that you will need to use a sub report to solve this issue.

Comment: Thanks Kalim, Please let me know if you get anything

Comment: What are your two parameters called? Or is this one parameter with 2 values?

Comment: I have only one parameter on ID, but the parameter can have multiple values including selection option "ALL", so that user can select all

Comment: Create a subreport with both tablix in them. Then make sure the subreport  executes for each value of your muti value parameter. This should solve your problem. This way both tablix 1 and 2 will display for your first parameter value first. And then the second parameter value will execute for both tablixes.