# Selecting multiple parameters for a report, how to create multiple pages per item in parameter list?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that is a form per order number selected prior to running report.  I want to make it so that you can select multiple order_nos from a list (populated by a query that runs first).  Right now, it throws an error saying ANY or ALL must be used.  I think it is trying to use both order_nos as the parameter for the report.  I want it to create the report using just one of the order_nos at a time, and just replicate the report several times.  Is this possible?

The attached photo shows what I tried to do and the error thrown.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyXkL.png)

Comment: could you provide a screenshot of  your report?

Comment: do you want the report layout or the data set?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create completely separate outputs then you will need to do this by creating a data driven subscription for your report.

The subscription will execute your report iteratively for each record produced in a preset master query that you create.

Each record in your master query should return all the order no's you wish to execute the report for.

However, if the report needs to remain interactive, and the order no's is only decided at runtime. Then i suggest you keep your report as is. Put a grouping on your tablix based on order no then apply a page break per group instance.

This will produce a single report output with each order no appearing on a different page.

As said above if you want a completely separate output (multiple excel/pdf file outputs) then you will need to use a data driven subscription.

If you need detailed steps on how to do either of the above then just let me know here and i can include steps.

Comment: Kalim, thanks for the answer.  I'll probably do the tablix grouping if that is possible.  Could you elaborate a bit more on that?

Comment: I've covered this exact topic in two other questions. Please see my responses there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33664532/how-to-get-multiple-pages-in-same-report-in-ssrs/33667778#comment55226580_33667778 and also this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31672462/ssrs-report-seperate-data-into-multiple-sheets/31673282#31673282 this should give you all the detail you need to implement the grouping and page breaking for each order no.

Comment: Kalim, it is actually a bit different in my case.  My tablix is not the entire report, it is embedded only as a portion of the report, which looks like a document.  I need a new instance of the report (document) to be created for each instance of the parameter. Can this be done?

Comment: If subscriptions are not an option then the only other possible suggestion is to use a combination of the above method along with an embedded subreport. You would need to create a new report, along with the tablix mentioned above, grouped on order no. You will need to ensure that for each instance of the order no a page break needs to occur. On the cell of your tablix insert a subreport. Link your existing report to this subreport. This will ensure that the entire report executes for each order no.

Comment: As i said above, i don't think its possible to produce separate outputs for each order no in this way, for that you need a subscription.